# NW.js / Node.js throws "SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol" error when using node-mssql / tedious

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-webkit, tedious

I found the answer to this problem already and just want to document my finding.

When using recent versions of **NW.js** (and **Node.js**), I was having problems with the **node-mssql** / **tedious** module. Even a task as simple as connecting to a **SQL Server** server would throw a *SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol* error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The reason why the error is thrown has to do with a change in **Node.js 12**. Since version 12, the **TLS** settings were tightened, and **TLS 1.2** is required by default. The *SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol* error would be thrown if the **SQL Server** server does not support **TLS 1.2**.

In **Node**, it is possible to change the default setting by using the command line flag `--tls-min-v1.0` when starting node. Since **NW** does not have a way to pass a command line flag to the **Node** context, the solution is to set a custom `cryptoCredentialsDetails` option in the connection configuration that specifies `minVersion: 'TLSv1'`, like the following:

```
mssql.connect({
    user: "this.user",
    password: "this.password",
    server: "this.server",
    database: "this.database",
    options: {
        cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
            minVersion: 'TLSv1'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: saved me hours of trouble

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're seeing (Deprecation Warning: Setting the TLS Server Name to an IP address is not permitted by RFC 6066) is related to using an IP address instead of a hostname in the TLS handshake, and it's usually more of a warning than a critical error. However, the Connection Error you're facing is more crucial, and it indicates a problem connecting to the SQL Server with SSL/TLS.

**Try adjusting the connection configuration by explicitly specifying the options and disabling SSL. For example:**

```js
const config = {
  user: 'your_username',
  password: 'your_password',
  server: 'your_sql_server',
  database: 'your_database',
  options: {
    encrypt: false, // Disable SSL/TLS
  },
};
```